# Mask R CNN, Preparing Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to train Mask R CNN with my own dataset. First I found a ready bottle dataset (70 images) and trained the model with 10 epochs. The accuracy was almost perfect. When I test with random images, the model was awesome.

[image]

Then I prepared my own dataset from [VGG Image Annotator- robots.ox.ac.uk](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via-1.0.6.html).

[image]

[image]

My goal is using segmentation and detection on cars and roads.  After I trained my model for 30 epochs, accuracy was terrible and it couldn't even detect 1 road or object from test images. Then I removed the road label from my data-set and prepared a model to detect only cars but my model couldn't do it as well.

1. So what are the things I could do wrong while preparing my data-set?
2. I have images from different heights. Maybe they are all must be almost the same?

   [image]
   [image]
3. Is it a good thing to draw a road like this? Or should I split it into parts?

   [image]
4. Is it good to label these roads that have tons of cars on them?
5. Should I draw boxes bigger or smaller?
6. Should I draw boxes even if only half of the car is on the image?
7. Should I prepare different images for cars and roads?. Maybe roads must be empty, there shouldn't be cars on it? I don't know.

Thank you for your time, have a nice day.

Comment: These are too many questions in one stack overflow question, I would split these into multiple questions. I'm still very interested in the answers!

Comment: But the questions are connected right? I wasn't sure what to or how to ask so I just put all the things in my mind to here